# Organization of unit tests with C++ Boost.Test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I've been reading about unit testing and I'm a little confused as to how the tests of different program components are organized. I'm assuming that each class usually has its own set of unit tests. If so:

1. Should every class to be tested get its own unit test .cpp file?
2. How to combine all the unit test .cpp files together?
3. Do the unit test files go into their own separate VS project? If so, is it run manually when desired, or can it somehow be connected to your actual project?
4. What is the purpose of test suits?

Answer (score 1):

It's all your choice.

1. if you want black box testing, sure. I've also done whitebox testing where the unit test CPP includes static definitions also included in the implementation cpp (`.ipp`)
2. Just link the object files containing tests, like you normally do. Static libraries with tests are fine too.
3. They usually do. You can of course have all the files (including tests) in a single project/library that your program as well as test runner depend on.

   But it's usually a good idea to not link/include the tests in your main program. Not only does this

   - reduce size
   - reduce risk of leaking information (e.g. test fixture data/details)

   It also gives you freedom to add dependencies for test only that you don't want to include in the deployed software (mock frameworks, SQLite e.g.)
4. The purpose is exactly to organize your tests. Say if you have tests that relate to "text file importing" in several translation units.

   In particular, test suites

   - can be nested,
   - act like namespaces (opening the same "suite" namespace in several translation units combines all the tests in that single suite)
   - can have "global" setup/teardown, and labels